# JQUERY: how to pause/start animation?

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery animation which contains about 300x functions as this one playing one after the other as a sequence:

```
$(".block").animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "slow");
```

1) How is it possible, by clicking on an anchor , to pause the whole thing and start it from where it was paused when clicking again (and not from the beginning)?

2) On another hand, say I have these for instance:

```
$(".block").animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "slow");
$(".block").animate({"right": "+=50px"}, "slow");
$(".block").animate({"top": "+=50px"}, "slow");...(x100)
```

How can I make them play one after the other without putting them as callbacks (I generate them via PHP and it would be kind of hard to generate them as callbacks of one another since there are more than 300 in total)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer 2), you can chain them like this:

```
a = $(".block");
a = a.animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "slow");
a = a.animate(...)
etc...
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/NwXMT/3/

Comment: I just tried to edit your fiddle to make it work with a.animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "slow"); and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Looks like it works to me: http://jsfiddle.net/NwXMT/4/ EDIT i see now, no it doesn't when you use `left`. Does `left` support the += operator?

Comment: Okay, I have good news for you! This is actually a bug that was fixed in JQuery 1.6.2 (see http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9237). Since JSFiddle uses 1.6.1, it doesn't work. You should be able to use `left` on your own page without a problem as long as you have 1.6.2 or higher.

Comment: thanks I'll try it on my host! By the way, do you have a clue for question 2? I tried Saeed Neamati's suggestion but it only works for animate, while I would want it to work for other functions too..

Comment: For that you'll need a plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Pause-Resume-animation

Answer (score 0):

To answer first question.

```
$('#anchorTagId').click(function(){
    // Caching the current position of the animated element.
    var currentLeft = $('.block').css('left');
    // Then stop the animation on that element.
    $('.block').stop();
    // Setting anchor's tag to start
});
```

Then on its next click

```
$('#anchorTagId').click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('start') {
        // Starting the animation from the cached position;
        return;
    }
    // Code to stop the animation. 
});
```

Comment: It only works for animate functions. Do you have a more universal method to do it so that it would work for any function?